# get a KEY, given a value, from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Have a registry of users, and we would like to input an email address, then return the UID.

Is there a way to do this in swift?

We would like the function to return this.

[image]

like we'd input user@user.com into the function and it will return gSVeU6....

Any tips and suggestions are really appreciated man.

Here is what the firebase JSON tree looks like
[image]

```
func findFriendsUIDFromFirebase(selectedFriendsEmail: String) {
    print("Hey from findFriendsUIDFromFirebase called")
    fir.child("registeredUsersOnPlatform").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            guard let allTheUsers = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else {
                print("Something is wrong with this snapshot")
                return
            }

            if let selectedUserUIDFromFirebase = allTheUsers.someKey(forValue: selectedFriendsEmail) {
                //DO STUFF
```

basically in this way we download everything locally then loop through the dictionary, but am looking for a better way, one that doesn't involving downloading the whole thing. Maybe something with a .equals()?

At the same time, for some reason when printing the dictionary, it seems to be stuck at 100 key-value pairs. when there are like 300ish pairs on the actual table. It's some clipping somewhere.

Comment: I don't know what is the structure in your code, and I understood that you want to get the key for a specific value ? If yes, do a loop through your keys and values

Comment: Yes actually we tried downloading the whole thing as a dictionary locally, then loop through to find the UID we want, but surely there is a better way 

Comment: Can you please provide your dictionary? so, i can understand your database structure

Comment: What is the purpose of getting a key for NoSQL schema ?

Comment: Well, basically in our structure, each user has an account with some items.  Basically we are trying something simple where one user can just pass an object to another.  

By first finding the friend's UID, then pushing the item over using that UID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get Key when create User in firebase you can get them in user callBack data like:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pwd) { (user, _) in
            print(user?.uid)
        }
```

Else if you want to get key from value in normal lists data so that use queryEqualToValue then print snapshot's child key

Comment: err.. im sorry but that's for just retrieving that particular user's UID upon authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to perform a [Firebase query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for the specific value you are looking for:

```
let queryEmail = "Userone@user.com"
fir.child("registeredUsersOnPlatform").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: queryEmail).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (querySnapshot) in
    for result in querySnapshot.children {
         let resultSnapshot = result as! DataSnapshot
         print (resultSnapshot.key)
    }
}
```

You can also limit the amount of query results you would like with `.queryLimited(toFirst: x)`